# JxBrowser fails to render a simple ag-grid page when using rxjs observable to fetch data from a REST service

Tags: angular, ag-grid-angular, jxbrowser

I am using JDK1.8 with JxBrowser 6.23.0, Angular 8 and ag-grid v2.0
JxBrowser works well when the rowData of the ag-grid is hard-coded json. But when I switch to fetch data from a back end REST service, it fails to render the page. It shows a bland screen with the message 'loading...'

The same URL works fine in stand-alone chrome browser.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are you not getting the data back from the service call, or are you getting data but it's not rendering?

Showing your code (a plunker would be good) would help folks to help you debug it.